# Can I have a click event for a complete Linear layout

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a linear layout and some buttons inside the layout.When click on Linear layout it should navigate to new page1, When click on button it should navigate to page2.

Comment: Please help me how can I achieve this functionality. I am beginner in xamarin

Comment: Are you working on Xamarin Native Android? Are you trying to change Fragments? From Fragment 1 thats a linear layout to Fragment 1 thats a second linear layout?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to achieve the result like this GIF?
[image]

If so, yes you can add the click event for your `LinearLayout`.There is my code.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"  android:id="@+id/my_ll">

<Button 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:text="click"
  android:id="@+id/button1"
 />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is background code.Add the different click listeners for linearlayout and button.

```
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayout my_ll = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.my_ll);
        Button button1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1); 
        my_ll.Click += My_ll_Click;
        button1.Click += Button1_Click;
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Activity2));
        StartActivity(intent);
    }

    private void My_ll_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,typeof(Activity1));
        StartActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Leon, Will the above code work for both xamarin forms and xamarin native

Comment: @nuggusubramanyam Are there any updates for this issue? If the reply is helpful, please mark it as an answer,  it will help others who have similar issue.